# Set Background image cause heavy page loading

Tags: css, html

I have page I set background image to it using the following code

```
<body class="homeBg">
```

where css looks like

```
.homeBg
{
    background:url(../images/home-bg.jpg) no-repeat scroll center top;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

this cause slow web site loading specially if u use mobile , any idea how to enhance that ,

Comment: Use a smaller image.

Comment: @putvande what do u mean by smaller image please

Comment: Smaller size, less bytes.

Comment: What does the Developer Console of Chrome tell you if you profile Network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what putvande meant was that the images are too large in terms of byte size (like over 4000 pixels wide or something) and/or the resolution might be over 72 dpi.  You should Google how to optimize images and learn about bytes.

If you're on a mobile use media queries with a smaller image. 
For example:

```
.homeBg
{
    background:url(../images/home-bg.jpg) no-repeat scroll center top;
}

 @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
 .homeBg
   {background:url(../images/home-bg-1000px.jpg) no-repeat scroll center top;}
 }


 @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .homeBg
    {background:url(../images/home-bg-for-mobile-size.jpg) no-repeat scroll center top; }
 }
```